# Change data type dynamically in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert the data type dynamically.

My code:

```
private static void updateValues(SqlDataReader reader)  
{
        USR_AddressItem item = new USR_AddressItem();
        Type ConvertNewType;
        ConvertNewType = Type.GetType(item.UserId.GetType().Name);
        item.UserId = (ConvertNewType)(reader[UserDAL.USR_Address.FieldNames.UserId]);

}
```

Here  data type only in dynamically. Because I want to assign value this variable in run time. I will get values from `SqlDataReader`. This reader return always string values. I am going to use this method globally.

Comment: What's "dynamic" about this question?

Comment: Dynamic type conversion is difficult, you often end up wanting to use a switch case for type conversions you've implemented, but find that you cannot switch a variable of type `Type`

Comment: Check my answer and enjoy. Piece of cake using generics!

Comment: `Type.GetType(item.UserId.GetType().Name);`  Love this :)
why not `item.UserId.GetType()`

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/Alxandr/6008481 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what you need is called *type inference*

You don't need to know the data type in advance, you let the runtime solve it on the fly, like this:

```
private static void updateValues(SqlDataReader reader)  
{
    USR_AddressItem item = new USR_AddressItem();
    item.UserId = GetConverter(item.UserId)(reader[UserDAL.USR_Address.FieldNames.UserId]);
}
```

And my magic is here:

```
static Func<string, T>  GetConverter<T>(T example)      
{
    return (x) => Convert<T>(x); 
}


static T Convert<T>(string val)
{
        Type destiny = typeof(T);

        // See if we can cast           
        try
        {
            return (T)(object)val;
        }
        catch { }

        // See if we can parse
        try
        {
            return (T)destiny.InvokeMember("Parse", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, null, new object[] { val });
        }
        catch { }

        // See if we can convert
        try
        {
            Type convertType = typeof(Convert);
            return (T)convertType.InvokeMember("To" + destiny.Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, null, new object[] { val });
        }
        catch { }

        // Give up
        return default(T);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In the example you show, it would be simpler to just say:

```
Userid = new System.Guid(value);
```

since the constructor of a `Guid` takes a string to create the object.

That is, unless you're trying to do something else, in which case please clarify your question!

Comment: -1; OP question is about converting a string into a GUID without using native code which I presume is just a generic example as the title of the questions is "Change data type dynamically in c#" not "How do I convert a string into a GUID".

Comment: Given the poor grammar of the post (I edited it initially to make it better), and the example code given, it was not clear to me that the OP intended it to be "dynamic" the way we normally think about dynamic. If that's what the OP really wants, they need to make it more clear.

Comment: sorry . I know that data type only in run time. this is my original code  `   USR_AddressItem item = new USR_AddressItem();
            Type ConvertNewType;
            ConvertNewType = Type.GetType(item.UserId.GetType().Name);
            item.UserId = (ConvertNewType)(reader[UserDAL.USR_Address.FieldNames.UserId]);`

Comment: @user2354274 Put that in your question, use the edit function. Don't worry too much about grammar or formatting if you find it difficult (you'll learn), the community should be able to sort that out.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a `Guid` it's going to be much different because there is no real **conversion.** See, building a `Guid` with a `string` must be done like this:

```
var guid = new Guid("DAABED91-39AC-4805-9015-1B03E4B5706A");
```

You could of course use `Reflection` for this, but it would be a pretty complex algorithm to determine what constructor to use for a type that doesn't have a real **conversion.**

However, for a number of other types you could consider something like this:

```
// would generate something like ToInt32...
var methodName = string.Format("To{0}", t.Name.Split('.').Last());

var methodInfo = Convert.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
if (methodInfo == null) { return default(t); }

var val = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { valToConvert });
```

**NOTE:** this code is untested. It's meant as a guide, and I think it's pretty close, but you may have to massage it a little.

Comment: sorry . I know that data type only in run time. this is my original code : `USR_AddressItem item = new USR_AddressItem(); Type ConvertNewType; ConvertNewType = Type.GetType(item.UserId.GetType().Name); item.UserId = (ConvertNewType)(reader[UserDAL.USR_Address.FieldNames.UserId]);`

Comment: @user2354274, so replace `t` with `ConvertNewType`.

Comment: How to assign value to item.UserId. it showing convertion error

Comment: @user2354274, you'll want to make your method generic (e.g. `ConvertType<T>`) so that you can cast the value from the invoke (e.g. `(T)methodInfo.Invoke...`). So, based on your current code, you'd call this **new method** after you determined the type you were converting to, and the **new method** would have the remainder of the code.