# How to change data types of properties in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, type-inference

Im trying to change data type of objects dynamically ,
here is my scenario
I have data in a data table , and i need to map it to objects in c#

Here are steps i have followed

1. Loop through data table and fetch each data row
2. get columns inside that loop
3. Pass column name , new object to assign values to properties , data table        cell value to new method.

here is sample code

```
            m1()
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in inputTable.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn col in inputTable.Columns)
                    {
                        m2(col.caption,row[col.caption].toString(),new product())
                    }
                }
            }

            m1(string columnName,string cellValue,product mappingEntity){
                foreach (var prop in entityToMap.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        if (prop.Name.ToLower() == column.ToLower())
                        {
                            prop.SetValue(entityToMap, GetConverter(t)(cellValue));
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (prop.Name == "Site")
                        {
                            entityToMap.Site = MapSite(column, cellValue, new Domain.Entities.Site());
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (prop.Name == "Product_categories")
                        {
                            entityToMap.Product_categories.Add(MapProductToCategory(column, cellValue, new Domain.Entities.ProductToCategory()));
                        }
                        else if (prop.Name == "Category_searchgroups")
                        {
                            entityToMap.Category_searchgroups.Add(MapCategoryToSearchGroup(column, cellValue, new Domain.Entities.CategoryToSearchGroup()));
                        }
            }
```

Now i need to dynamically change data types of assigning values.

```
 if (prop.Name.ToLower() == column.ToLower())
    {
      Type t = prop.PropertyType;
      prop.SetValue(entityToMap, GetConverter(t)(cellValue));
      break;
    }
```

so i have found type inference question here
[Change data type dynamically in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676077/change-data-type-dynamically-in-c-sharp)

```
 static Func<string, T> GetConverter<T>(T value)
        {
            return (x) => Convert<T>(x);
        }
    static T Convert<T>(string val)
    {
        Type destiny =typeof(T);

        // See if we can cast           
        try
        {
            return (T)(object)val;
        }
        catch { }

        // See if we can parse
        try
        {
            return (T)destiny.InvokeMember("Parse", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, null, new object[] { val });
        }
        catch { }

        // See if we can convert
        try
        {
            Type convertType = typeof(Convert);
            return (T)convertType.InvokeMember("To" + destiny.Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public, null, null, new object[] { val });
        }
        catch { }

        // Give up
        return default(T);
    }
```

the issue is i have reflection object , i cant pass reflection object because it's not valid at that context , 
Can anyone help me to resolve this ??
thanks

Comment: What is the type for `entityToMap` ?

Comment: why don't you use `Convert.ChangeType()`?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://community.dynamics.com/gp/b/gpdynland/archive/2017/02/20/converting-a-datatable-to-objects-in-c

Comment: I'd consider using something like [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) to handle this.  It can give you a nice structured way to control the field mappings. Plus, you don't have to deal with the reflection directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but it sounds like.

```
public static T RowToObjectClass<T>(DataRow r) where T : new()
{
    T obj = new T();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite))
    {
        pi.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(r[pi.Name], pi.PropertyType));
    }
    return obj;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("date", typeof(string)));

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1.ToString(), new DateTime(2018, 1, 1).ToString() });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2.ToString(), new DateTime(2018, 2, 2).ToString() });

    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row:   " + r[0].ToString() + " (" + r[0].GetType() + ")" + ", " + r[1].ToString() + " (" + r[1].GetType() + ")");
        MyClass c = RowToObjectClass<MyClass>(r);
        Console.WriteLine("Class: " + c.Id.ToString() + " (" + c.Id.GetType() + ")" + ", " + c.Date.ToString() + " (" + c.Date.GetType() + ")");
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kara  , your answer guided me to correct one.
thanks again.